# smtplib - sender is ignored or email not received

Tags: python, smtplib

I have an SMTP server running on localhost:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

Problems:

1. If I am using gmail config I can send an email from python code. However, the 'From' user is being ignored and it defaults to the username associated with the login...
2. If I am not using a login based server (gmail or other), emails are being sent but not received

I am trying to generate an email from a 'do_not_reply@abc.com' but I cannot get it to work. What am I missing?

Comment: This might help with #1: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en

Comment: What does running an SMTP *server* have to do with your question? How does that relate to sending email "from python code?"

Comment: If I'm not running this nothing gets sent...